# No shape named intersection-1 is known

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

I'm trying to buld the example called **Elliptic Curve Group Operations** from the [TikZ for Cryptographers website](https://www.iacr.org/authors/tikz/). I have PGF 3.0.1, installed in my home dir under `~/texmf/tex/latex/pgf_3.0.1/`.

But I'm not able to compile the example. I'm running

```
pdflatex --shell-escape ec-rules.tex
```

Unfortunately I get the error:

```
Package pgf Error: No shape named intersection-1 is known
```

I have no clue, what's the issue (since I never worked with intersections).

Comment: that means two paths don't intersect

Comment: It is working as expected for the file given there.

Comment: Before the error I got a warning: *Package pgf Warning: Plot data file ec_group_operations.curve-22.table' not fo
und. on input line 61.* Do you have `gnuplot` installed? Cos I don't, so...

Comment: Good match @Sigur. I installed `gnuplot` and it works now!

Answer (score 1):

As figured out by @Sigur, I had to install `gnuplot`.